# How do I move 1st element in array to the last position in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I have a powershell array with about 10 items. I'm trying to take the 1st element (0) of the array and move it to the last item. There will still be (only) 10 items in the array at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind creating a *new* array, here's a concise solution:

```
$a = 1..10 # sample array: 1, 2, ..., 10

$a = $a[1..($a.count-1)] + $a[0]
```

<sup>minmaxavg eventually came up with an even more concise alternative in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324792/45375):
`$a[1..($a.count-1) + 0]`

Performance-wise the two solutions are virtually identical.

Also, their [`[array]::Copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy) solution is a more efficient, in-place alternative - at the expense of being more complex to write; it could be simplified somewhat to:

`$first = $a[0]; [array]::Copy($a, 1, $a, 0, $a.Count - 1); $a[-1] = $first`</sup>

`$a` now contains:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
```

- `$a[1..($a.count-1)]` returns a *new array* that contains all elements of `$a` starting with the element at index `1`, i.e., starting with the *2nd* element.

  - `1..($a.count-1)` is a *range* expression which itself creates an array - the array of indices to extract from the input array.
  - As an aside:

    - PowerShell supports index `-1` to refer to an array's *last* element, `-2` to refer to the second-to-last, and so on.
    - However, using negative indices in a *range* may not do what you expect; e.g., `1..-1` does *not* extract all elements from the 2nd to the second-to-last one ([GitHub issue #7940](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7940) proposes new syntax similar to C#'s ranges to support this use case); instead, it extracts elements with indices `1`, `0`, and `-1` (the last), because these are the elements of the array (of indices) that the range operator (`..`) generates.
- `+ $a[0]` "appends" the *first* element to that new array; technically, this creates *another* array that is the concatenation of the elements of the LHS and the RHS.
- In summary, *3* arrays were created in the process: 2 auxiliary, transient ones behind the scenes, plus the result array assigned back to `$a`.
- Therefore, while using the range operator (`..`) to extract array slices and using `+` to concatenate arrays is very convenient, it is not *efficient*, though with small arrays that usually doesn't matter - beware of "appending" to an array in a loop with `+=`, however, as you'll be recreating the array in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate the array in-place, this is more efficient than manually iterating and shifting elements in Powershell (.NET `Array.Copy` is analogous to Java `System.arraycopy`):

```
New-Variable -Name first -Value $arr[0] -Scope Private
[array]::Copy($arr, 1, $arr, 0, $arr.Length - 1)
$arr[$arr.Length - 1] = $Private:first
```

If copying is desirable (10 elements should be ok):

```
$arr = $arr[1 .. ($arr.Length - 1) + 0]
```

Powershell allows combination of two or more ranges through the `+` operator. Especially if you intend the array to be immutable, this should be the most optimal solution.

Comment: Nicely done, though I suggest using just `$first = ...`  and `... = $first` to avoid creating a distraction.

Comment: Another tip for streamlining the 1st solution: `$arr[$arr.Length - 1]` can be simplified to `$arr[-1]` (but `1 .. ($arr.Length - 1)` in the 2nd solution can _not_ be simplified to `1.. -1`).